# How could I limit the password to be a certain number of characters?

Tags: php, html, attributes, password-protection

I need to limit the password characters to be 10 only as an example, not less not more..

There's only "maxlength" in HTML attributes, but there's no such "length" or "minlenght" to be used!

I have this code:

```
<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="9" pattern="\d+" value="<?php echo htmlentities($password); ?>" />
```

How could I limit the password to be a certain number of characters?

Comment: DON'T. Do not *ever* limit the length of a password. Most importantly you're putting a hard limit on how secure a given password can be, and if a user wants to enter 200 random chars they should be allowed to. Secondly, a password with a set limit on length screams out "I store passwords as plain text" because a hash of a password of *any* length is always the same length. Do. Not. Do. This.

Comment: @Sammitch: I see, thank you for such a valuable information..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5. For me it's a good solution.

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="form">
    <input pattern=".{10}" title="10 characters" placeholder="10 characters" name="password" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Test" />
</form>
```

See in action: **http://jsfiddle.net/a4B7z/**.

*Not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.*

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful, and I could use another `pattern` and `maxlenght` as well..

Comment: I appreciate your understanding, and I hope you help me in this issue http://goo.gl/j82ql , too )

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to do it. First attach the `onblur` event:

```
<input ... onblur="verifyMinLength(this, 10)"... />
```

and then in JavaScript:

```
function verifyMinLength(o, len) {
    if (o.value.length < len) {
        alert('The password must be 10 characters in length.');
        o.focus();
    }
}
```

of course this could be fancier. You could leverage a label that's placed next to the `input` control instead of the `alert`. You could also use CSS to change the border of the `input` control so the user gets some more feedback. But that's all up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use strlen?

```
if(strlen($password) < 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate the password after it is entered:

```
if (strlen($password) != 10)
{
  echo 'password must be 10 characters';
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you found a solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I see you already have a lot of good answers here. Using a validation pattern like freejosh posted is the way I would do it. It seems to me to be the simplest and cleanest approach.

**BUT.....**

I have to agree with sammitch on this one. I would never limit a passwords length for the reasons he already stated. Having a minimum length can be a good thing since it forces the password to have a certain number of characters therefore (hopefully) increasing its security, but I would never give a limit for maximum length